# Bash: can't create lower case out of script argument?

Tags: bash, shell

```
#!/bin/sh
var="$1";
OUTPUT=$(echo ${$var,,});
echo $OUTPUT
```

I tried every possible combination, including escaping certain characters.

I just cant get shell to output my script argument lower cased.

Error:

```
createmodule.sh: 26: createmodule.sh: Bad substitution
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a mistake, try this instead :

```
#!/bin/bash
var="$1"
OUTPUT=${var,,}
echo $OUTPUT
```

You have had a `$` in excess.

As seen in discussion, never call scripts with `sh script` if you are not sure that the wanted shell is really a `sh` one. A better approach is to put the good shebang like `#!/bin/bash`, and then `chmod+x script.sh` and finally `./script.sh`

Comment: Do you have the `/bin/bash` shebang like me ? Just edited a few seconds ago.

Comment: I have /bin/sh, as seen in my code. Would it make a difference? Edit: I changed it to /bin/bash, still erroring me.

Comment: Sure ! When you write `/bin/sh`, you explicitly ask what's linked to `/bin/sh` to run in `POSIX` mode like when `bash` is linked as `/bin/sh`

Comment: Yeah. But it's still erroring me out, and I have no idea why. You can try it yourself.

Comment: In your case, you have the `bash` tag, and you try some `bash4` features, so calling `/bin/bash` is necessary. If "that doesn't work", then you don't have `bash4`, run `bash -version` to ensure.

Comment: GNU bash, version 4.2.24(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Comment: sputnick, i'll accept your answer. My problem was that I called my scripts with the 'sh' command, instead of "./" as I saw on pastebin. Thanks for helping me figuring this out.

Comment: Heh, that's why I told you that the shell that is called is very important.